# Redirect AzureWebsites www to non-www (certificate error)

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I've tried many online solutions to get an azure site to redirect from www to non-www.  The target site is successfully running as follows:
https://carterminal.online

I'm trying to get the www versions of the url to redirect to non-www. The last version of the rewrite urls I tried was the following (I also remember to clear the browser redirect cache):

```
  <rule name="HTTPS and non-WWW only" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://carterminal.online/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
```

Credit: [Windows Azure: redirect website from www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949986/windows-azure-redirect-website-from-www-to-non-www)

However, when I insert the `www` in the browser, I'm getting a certificate error which refers to the azurewebsites certificate, not the custom one installed for `carterminal.online`.

I'm a bit confused as to why the wrong certificate is being consulted when using `www` - how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `www` version of your domain configured as a Custom Domain. Your SSL certificate does suppport the `www` version though, so that part is good.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that?  Is that in Azure, or at the DNS?

Comment: Your DNS configuration is good. You need to go into the App Service in the Azure Portal, and then click Custom Domains on the left side. You'll see an entry there already for `carterminal.online` and you just need to add another entry for `www.carterminal.online`.

Comment: Great thanks. We added a CNAME record on the DNS and we added the extra entry on Azure and that did the trick.  I'm not sure if I should remove the web.config rule as well?

Comment: You still need the web.config rule for this to work. The redirect wouldn't happen without it.